# Не подгружается СSS на мобильной версии?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Это скриншот верстки на Chrome devTools]

[image: На первых двух скринах все нормально]

[image: Но входит телефон на хостинг возникает проблема]

[image: Подгружается старая версия main.css или вовсе неработает]

[image]

Я пытался несколько раз обновлять файлы ([вот код](http://%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)) на хостинге, но результат тот же.
В ПК версии все нормально, а в мобильной нет.

Comment: Какие именно стили (какого) блока или элемента у вас не подгружаются? Уточните, что именно вы ожидаете. При просмотре десктопной и моб версии вашей страницы (http://y70810lm.beget.tech/) никаких подозрений что-то не подгружается не возникает.  И навсякий случай: после изменения стилей, вы кеш на смартфоне чистили или в инкогнито смотрели?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте тег `<head></head>` найдите строку где вы подключаете `main.css` и замените `main.css -> main.css?v=1` и заливайте на сервер.